# PRESTASHOP - Como fazer aparecer os atributos e características no Front-End?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, e-commerce

Cadastrei algumas categorias, coloquei no menu, depois fiz os cadastros dos atributos e das características, cadastrei alguns produtos e fiz as associações mas os atributos não aparecem ao ser clicado na categoria. No anexo explica com detalhes o que não estou conseguindo fazer aparecer.

Obs:

Estou utilizando o tema que vem com a instalação, com o Prestashop 1.6.

Espero ter sido claro o suficiente.

agradeço pela atenção!

Anderson

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O módulo "Bloco Navegação em Camadas" resolvem meu problema. Deixo a resposta caso alguém também tenha a mesma dificuldade.

Atenciosamente,

Anderson